# PHP Include Always Fails

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-fcgid, suexec

- Apache HTTP Server 2.2.21 with VirtualHosts under SuExec
- PHP 5.3.8 via fcgid
- Arch Linux 2011.08.19

I am in the process of migrating from shared hosting to VPS. The code I had ran fine before the move but is now failing at this line:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'includes/content/header.php');
```

Error log says:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening
>   required '/srv/www/hostname/public/includes/content/header.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /srv/www/hostname/public/index.php on line 3

I tried the same line without the document root part, with and without `./`, file in the same directory, etc. with no luck. No difference with `require`, `include_once`, or `include`, either. Yet, I can verify that the file exists at that exact location by copy-pasting from the error log and `cd`ing to it.

I asked this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939803/php-include-always-fails) and somebody told me it was likely a server issue so I'm restating here. (The most similar question I could find here was [never answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/293143/php-fopen-always-fails-with-permission-denied)) Summary of attempts:

- No combination of permissions helps (on directories or files); have tried from 644 to 777.
- All of the files are chown'd by the SuExec user/group.
- PHP reports itself as running under the correct user/group.
- Apache & SuExec error logs report nothing.
- Safe Mode is set to "Off" in `php.ini`.
- `dirname(__FILE__)` and `exec('pwd')` return the same as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but without the trailing slash; prefixing with one or the other makes no difference.
- `include`, `include_once`, `fread`, `file_exists`, `file_get_contents`, and `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` all return false.
- `set_include_path()` has no effect.
- Running `require` via `php-cgi` directly from the command line returns Internal Server Error while `include` returns blank output; running either via `php` returns blank output.

Here's my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@hostname.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/hostname/public/"
    ServerName hostname.com
    ServerAlias www.hostname.com
    SuexecUserGroup hostname hostname
    ErrorLog "/srv/www/hostname/logs/error.log"
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog "/srv/www/hostname/logs/access.log" combined

    <Directory /srv/www/hostname/public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # http://www.linode.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2982
    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <IfModule !mod_php5_filter.c>
    <IfModule !mod_php5_hooks.c>
    <IfModule mod_actions.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        AddHandler php-fcgi .php
        Action php-fcgi /fcgid-bin/php-fcgid-wrapper
        Alias /fcgid-bin/ /srv/www/hostname/fcgid-bin/

        <Location /fcgid-bin/>
            SetHandler fcgid-script
            Options +ExecCGI
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Location>

        ReWriteEngine On
        ReWriteRule ^/fcgid-bin/[^/]*$ / [PT]
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So, what's the deal? Does `/srv/www/hostname/public/includes/content/header.php` exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) set to something other than a parent directory of `/srv/www/hostname/public/includes/content/`.  This would block opening or including that file.  Also make sure that the file you are opening isn't a symlink to something outside your open_basedir.

This would normally print a Warning-level message indicating that the file was blocked due to open_basedir, but if you have the errors disabled (or at least E_WARNING disabled) then you would not see the message.

Comment: That did it! I didn't realize that `open_basedir` was unaffected by Safe Mode being off—it was looking in `/srv/http/` but not `/srv/www/`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have apparamor installed and if so does it limit what apache process can access? (check /etc/apparmor.d )

Additionally try doing something like this:

sudo -u hostname cat /srv/www/hostname/public/includes/content/header.php

What does it give you?

Comment: Also check for selinux (`/var/log/audit.log` or `/var/log/audit/audit.log` in most distributions).  Either way, the problem may be a limitation on php-cgi, not on apache itself.

Comment: No apparmor, no SELinux. This is Arch Linux which comes with nothing but the bare minimum. I've installed nothing in regard to security; just basic daemons (httpd, sshd, pure-ftpd, tomcat7, etc.) and their dependencies.

sudo -u cat command gives me the contents of the file.